# Зачем нужны inner классы в интерфейсах в Java?

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс, inner

На мой взгляд, интерфейсы служат для разделения абстракции и реализации. Собственно, зачем может понадобиться внутри интерфейса создавать класс, который будет обладать некоторой реализацией?
Хотелось бы увидеть реальный пример использования внутренних классов в интерфейсах, чтобы понять, как такая особенность Java может быть использована.

Comment: Я видел такое один раз - внутри интерфейсов были внутренние классы, которые могли создавать объекты, реализующие эти интерфейсы, и помойка всяких утильных методов. На мой взгляд, это не правильно, по той же причине, которую указали вы. Просто, иногда, то, что что-то можно сделать, не значит что это нужно делать :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Пробежался структурным поиском по своему CLASSPATH и выловил следующие примеры:

1. **Интерфейс как пространство имен**

   1. Самое частое - статический `еnum`, связнанный предметной областью с интерфейсом, объявленный внутри интерфейса. Интерфейс в данном случае играет роль пространства имен.

      ```
      public interface Foo {
        void foo(Bar bar);

        static enum Bar { BAR1, BAR2, BAR3 }
      }
      ```

      Пример:

      - [`com.google.common.util.concurrent.Service`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/18.0/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Service.java#Service)

   ---

   2. Похожий вариант - класс, описывающий value-тип, связанный с интерфейсом.

      ```
      public interface Foo {
        void foo(Bar bar);

        static class Bar {
          private final String id;
          public Bar(Sting id) { this.id = id; }
          public String getId() { return id; }
        }
      }
      ```

      Пример:

      - [`org.hibernate.persister.entity.Queryable`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/org/hibernate/persister/entity/Queryable.java#Queryable)
      - [`io.undertow.security.api.AuthenticationMechanism`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/io.undertow/undertow-core/1.2.10.Final/io/undertow/security/api/AuthenticationMechanism.java#AuthenticationMechanism)

   ---

   3. Несколько маленьких классов внутри интерфейса реализующих другой очень узкий интерфейс. Интерфейс используется только как пространство имен.

      ```
      public interface Convertor {
        String convert(Object arg);
      }

      public interface Convertors {
        static class Convertor1 implements Convertor { String convert(Object arg) { /* ... */ }}
        static class Convertor2 implements Convertor { String convert(Object arg) { /* ... */ }}
        static class Convertor3 implements Convertor { String convert(Object arg) { /* ... */ }}        
      }
      ```

      Пример:

      - [`org.hibernate.tuple.TimestampGenerators`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/org/hibernate/tuple/TimestampGenerators.java#TimestampGenerators)

   ---

   4. Исключение, связанное с интерфейсом.

      ```
      public interface Foo {
        void foo() throws BarException;

        static class BarException extends Exception {
           // ...
        }
      }
      ```

      Пример:

      - [`org.hibernate.boot.spi.InFlightMetadataCollector`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.CR3/org/hibernate/boot/spi/InFlightMetadataCollector.java#InFlightMetadataCollector.DuplicateSecondaryTableException)

   ---

   5. Интерфейс объявляет внутри себя вспомогательные helper-классы с логикой, которые предлагает использовать реализациям.

      Пример:

      - [`org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteBufferPool`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/9.3.2.v20150730/org/eclipse/jetty/io/ByteBufferPool.java#ByteBufferPool)
      - `com.mysql.jdbc.SocketMetadata` (5.1.39)

   ---

   6. Интерфейс объявляет внутри себя готовую реализацию-заглушку.

      ```
      public interface Foo {
        Bar foo();

        static class FooImpl implements Foo {
          @Override 
          public void foo() { return null; }
        }
      }
      ```

      Пример:

      - [`org.junit.Test`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/org/junit/Test.java#Test)
      - [`com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistryListener`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.codahale.metrics/metrics-core/3.0.2/com/codahale/metrics/MetricRegistryListener.java#MetricRegistryListener)

   ---

   7. Интерфейс объявляет внутри себя Singleton, потому что "почему бы и нет": и так антипаттерн, так хоть локализовать его.

      Пример:

      - [`org.asynchttpclient.channel.ChannelPoolPartitioning`](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/client/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/channel/ChannelPoolPartitioning.java)

---

2. **Аннотация + обработчик**

   Статический класс реализующий некий интерфейс внутри интерфейса-аннотации описывающий логику этой аннотации.
   Код, анализирующий аннотации скорее всего доберется до этого статического класса через рефлексию.

   ```
     @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
     public @interface Foo {
         // annotation fields

         static class FooHandler implements Handler<Foo> {
             public void handle(Foo foo, Object arg) {
               //...
             }
         }
     }

     public interface Handler<A extends Annotation> {
         void handle(A a, Object arg);
     }
   ```

   Примеры:

   - `javax.annotation.RegEx`
   - `javax.annotation.Nonnull`
   - `javax.annotation.Nonnegative`